# Vue - get element calling function wihout (event)

Tags: javascript, html, function, events, vue.js

I need to get the element calling my function in Vue. But there is no event. I'm calling the method in my `v-for`. Here is my HTML code:

```
<select id="sel_subUse" v-on:change="calculateARV(event, index)">
    <option v-for="subUse in filter(event, index)" value="subUse">{{ subUse }}</option>
</select>
```

I tried using `event.target` anyways but to no avail. How do I get the calling element?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$event`, not `event` as the parameter. Then you'll have the event.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers

Comment: It doesn't work. I've used `event` without the $ sign in other places, and they work just fine.

Comment: You can ignore the link to the documentation if you'd like I guess.

Comment: Was that sarcasm? I followed the documentation. It doesn't work. There isn't an event (v-on:something) in this case. That's probably why it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. Are you talking about the event from here? `v-on:change="calculateARV(event, index)"`. If so, that needs to become `calculateARV($event, index)` and in your callback the first argument will be the DOM event. If `event` is actual data you need (only suspecting it because of `filter(event, index)`) then you can do `calculateARV(event, index, $event)` then the third argument will be the DOM event.

Comment: If you were doing `v-on:change="calculateARV"` you wouldn't need to pass event yourself. It would be available as the first argument in the method.

Comment: No, it's not v-on:change. I'm talking about `v-for="subUse in filter(event, index)"` Please read my question again.

Comment: All right. No event would be available there. Ideally on change you'd update some data and use that instead of expecting the event.